# Recover deleted files from Xcode4

Tags: xcode, git

I am new to git and to Xcode, and mac in general, so here's my question

I accidentally added my whole desktop to a project i was working on. When I wanted to delete the files, Xcode asked me if I wanted to delete them from disk and I said yes. The problem is that the project itself was in a folder inside my desktop and it took out everything. I had not committed my changes in the git local branch. Is there any way to undo what I did?

I appreciate whatever help I can get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have not committed, Git cannot help you bring back your project. You will have to look at other alternatives ( like TimeMachine if you had it setup? )

Comment: This is what i feared. I had not set up TimeMachine, so I think I lost a whole months work. And probably my job.

Comment: @AndresBucci - Sorry to hear about that.

Comment: I'm trying to use another service to recover from disk, let's see how that goes.

Comment: I'm trying to get it from a backup, but how? it keeps invalidating the one I restore from the backup. or where would I find the .h & .m files?

Answer (score 1):

If anyone's experiencing trouble with this problem, I nearly went back in my project and changed everything all over again but then remembered that it may not have been legit deleted yet. That is all to say that you should **CHECK YOUR TRASH** first! I don't know why it didn't occur to me until awhile after I had accidentally deleted it, but I ended up finding it in the Trash, so I'm thankful for that. Hope I've saved someone a whole lot of trouble!

Answer (score 0):

Stop using the HDD immediately. Get Data Recovery help. Top of the line Data Recovery services may charge 1K-3K but can do an amazing job. Worth trying if your job is on the line.

Also, don't lose heart. Doing it the second time (if it comes to that) will take much shorter time than the original one.

Comment: This is what I did. I started from scratch and managed to do the essentials in two days. Now i need to do all the extra stuff